# Does Buckshot proc Blackcleaver 3 times?

Tags: league-of-legends

Bucketshot works as increasing damage for each bullet that hit the target, so does it proc Blackcleaver 3 times if all three bullets hit the target?

Might this make Black Cleaver viable on Graves if so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start, Black Cleaver is already fairly viable on him. While it's still probably better to build him as a traditional AD Carry, building him as an AD Caster does have its merits.

Buckshot's tooltip states:
Shoots three bullets in a cone, each dealing X(+AD) physical damage to all enemies in their path. Enemies hit with multiple bullets take 40% damage from each additional bullet.

Now, this is vague when it comes to your question: does it actually hit multiple times, or is the damage added into one hit?

I entered a custom game, and tested it out, by hitting a minion at point blank range with buckshot. I did about 150 damage, and only one number showed up. As the base damage is 60 and the ratio is 80% bonus, there was no way at level 1 for me to do 150 with a single bullet.

As this attack still only did damage once, it would only apply one stack of Black Cleaver.

Comment: That's what I figured, I just didn't have the time to test it myself. Thanks for that, I figured it was only one proc but I was hopeful haha.

Comment: Also note that I verified this today in a match as well. Not sure how I feel about building Black Cleaver on Graves though, still going to need a few more matches for that.